# Как организовать работу скрипта на другом ресурсе?

Tags: php, html5, angularjs, api, iframe

Здравствуйте!

Есть небольшой сервис, у которого есть калькулятор.

Нужно как-то разрешить пользователям устанавливать этот калькулятор на сайт.
Но что бы они могли это делать только после регистрации, и получив определённый код для определённого сайта.

Подскажите, может есть готовые решения, или в какую сторону копать? Раньше не сталкивался с этим совсем, даже не знаю с чего начать ;(

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: iframe запрещает менятся данными, пробуйте через подзапросы

Comment: @nick_n_a, а можно поподробнее, пожалуйста?

Comment: iframe может работать с [postMessage](https://vexell.ru/2013/06/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-json-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-iframe-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87/).

Comment: Вообщем наверное самый простой вариант это через ключ. есть ключ, и location.href сайта.  по ключу и url фомируете урл к iframe.

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, а можно какой-нибудь банальный пример, что бы понять о чём речь и что гуглить :)

Comment: Приблизительно принцип работы, могу описать в ответе

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, будьте так любезны :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов такой.

У вас есть страница регистрации после чего клиент получает key.
В БД  у вас хранится ключ и url сайта.

У вас есть скрипт который вставляет iframe с урлом.

```js
var youCalc = (function (window) {
     function Calc(window) {
        var key = '',
        location = window.location.hostname,
        elem = null,
        iframe = null, 
        path = 'http://path/to/site';
        
        function createPath() {
           path += '?site=' + location + "&key=" + key;
        }
        
        this.setKey = function (k) {
             key = k;

             return this;
         }
         this.setElem = function (el) {
             elem = el;

             return this;
         }
         
         this.getKey = function (k) {
             return key;
         }
         
         this.init = function() {
            if(key && location && elem) {
                createPath();
                iframe = window.document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.src = path;
                elem.appendChild(iframe);
            } else {
              alert('Введите обязательные параметры')
            }
            
         }
     }
  
     return new Calc(window);
  
})(window);


/*На сайте всбавляем такой код*/

youCalc.setKey('asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd')
       .setElem(document.getElementById('forCalc'))
       .init()
```

```html
<div id="forCalc"></div>
```

Ну а на Вашем сайте делаете проверку в зависимости от Вашего фреймворка. 
Приблизительно так:

```
...
  if(!isset($_GET['site'])) {
      // проверка наличия url
  }
  if(!isset($_GET['key'])) {
       // проверка наличия ключа
  }
  user = $this->model->getUser($_GET['site'], $_GET['key']);
  if(!isset(user)) {
      // проверка наличия пользователя
  }
  $this->display(); //вывод главного шаблона калькулятора если всё успешно
...
```

Comment: дак, я могу легко поменять  location в скрипте и "увести" с другого сайта..

Comment: тогда выдавайте токен, запрос location  + key и выдать токен

Comment: В теории, кстати, можно реализовать это через [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: с токенами ни разу не сталкивался, можете дать ссылку, как ими пользоваться?))

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/145988/